# How to change a control property (FlatStyle) in base form?

Tags: c#, inheritance

This might be kind of beginner question but I searched and didn't find any clear answer!

**The main question is:** How to inherit properties of a control (specially `FlatStyle`) from a base form which doesn't have that control in C#?

**Details:** I have `Form1` inherited from `baseForm`. `baseForm` has a `Panel` and a `Label` control but no `Button`. In `Form1` I added a button named `Button1`. How can I change the style of that `Button` through the `baseFrom`?
I don't want to create a custom control or redesign the button using rectangles or similar ways, but only change that property for all buttons in my application.

---

**UPDATE:** I want all of the buttons to be affected, whether they already exist or just added. Not matter in which -if any- container they are.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You'd need at least 10 good reasons to do something unwise like this.  You didn't give enough.  If you want to implement a theme then just also create buttons that are theme-aware.

Comment: @HansPassant I personally don't think having the need of setting the flat style on some buttons on winforms needs all those much reasons or the complications of a complete theme engine :-)

Comment: @HansPassant What is a theme-aware button? If it's something like custom button, I have to mention that I don't want my project to be full of custom objects because of necessity of a few parameter change.

Comment: A Winforms programmer that doesn't like classes is like a fish that doesn't like water.  Too much floppin' around.  Long term, take a good look at WPF, you'll like it better.

Answer (score 3):

In `baseForm`, you could hook the `ControlAdded` event on the `Panel` where the `Button` is to be added, and style appropiately via code. This will work for every form inherited from `baseForm`.

For example (in `baseForm`)

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
  public BaseForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    // "myPanel" is the panel where the button will be added in inherited forms
    myPanel.ControlAdded += myPanel_ControlAdded;
  }

  private void myPanel_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
  {
    var button = e.Control as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
      button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
      button.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
  }
}
```

Just made a really quick test... it works even in design mode:

[image: Screenshot]

As an alternative, if you are going to use heavily styled buttons everywhere in your application, you may consider creating a custom control inheriting from `Button`, and assign the properties there, like:

```
public class FlatButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
  public FlatButton()
  {
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  }
}
```

After building, you will find it in the Toolbox (under "[Your Project's] components" tab), or you can cram it on your own control library (in a different solution) and add it permanently to the Toolbox in Visual Studio.

Comment: This only makes changes in first level children of that panel, not nested ones. For example if we have a SplitContainer contained by `myPanel`, it won't make any changes to the buttons in SplitContainer.

Comment: As I said, you put this code on the control where the button is to be added. I answered your question, where you did only mention a panel. If you want something else, add it to the question. I also specified an alternative method which works everywhere.

Comment: I appreciate that and I added to the question.
As I mentioned, it's not needed to use a customized control, since all that I want to change is FlatStyle.
Could you please make an update and explain how this code can affect all the buttons, whether they existed before or just added?

Comment: Read my answer, just under the screenshots, it says `as an alternative...`... disregard the "heavily styled" part, it'd work for any kind of styled button, as long as you style them via the built-in properties. Custom-drawing would require additional work, but styling via properties is explained there

Comment: (if you already had buttons you'd have to convert them to your button descendant, but that should be a simple search & replace on your `.Designer.cs` files

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make use of [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)

You can use a [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) query to do this. This will query everything on the form that is type `Button`

```
var c = from controls in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
              select controls;
foreach(var control in c)
    control.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Comment: This works, although it needs to be recursive (`this.Controls` will only give first-child controls, not nested ones)